# Dagger 2: NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/producers/ProducerModule

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to integrate Dagger 2 with eclipse and the libs that I have used are as follows:

```
dagger-2.0.jar
dagger-compiler-2.0.jar
guava-13.0.1.jar
javawriter-1.0.5.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
```

Java Compiler -> Annotation processing has been enabled
All the above have been added to the Factory Path

But I get the following error when I build the project:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/producers/ProducerModule at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor.initSteps(ComponentProcessor.java:90)    BuildConfig.java    /DIDemo/gen/com/example/didemo  line 0  Java Problem
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Please do not follow up your question with "someone? anyone?"; you've done that 3 separate times, [each time within 15 minutes of posting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/966739/sunny?tab=activity&sort=comments). It is not a constructive use of comments and won't help your question get noticed any faster.

Comment: @JeffBowman: My bad on the follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `dagger-2.0` and so forth, you'll need a separate `dagger-producers` artifact, available from the [Maven Central Repository search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.dagger%22) linked from the [Dagger 2 GitHub page](https://github.com/google/dagger).

As of right now (October 2015), the latest file is named `dagger-producers-2.0-beta.jar`.

Comment: The error has gone but .apt-generated folder is not being created. Could you please help with that?

Comment: Actually now I am able to get the generated folder but DaggerXXXXXComponent file is missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906199/dagger-2-no-implementation-generated-for-component-interface

Could you please help? Thanks